# cordovaAppRate : nothing happens when i click 'Rate now'

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement cordovaAppRate in an Ionic app, i already set the configs, and the dialog box with the options "Remind me later", "Rate now", and "No thanks" is successfully displayed, But when i click the link "Rate now", nothing happens!

I'm testing with an actual device with Android 5.1.1

here's my cordovaAppRate configs

```
  .config( function($cordovaAppRateProvider) {
    var preferences = {
      language: 'de',
      appName: 'MyAppName',
      openStoreInApp: false,
      androidURL: 'market://details?id=myapp.id',
      iosURL: 'myapp.id'
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      $cordovaAppRateProvider.setPreferences(preferences);
    }, false);
  })
```

This is the function that triggers the dialog box

```
$scope.rate = function() {
  if (typeof AppRate != 'undefined') {
    $cordovaAppRate.promptForRating(true);
  };
}
```

any idea of why the "Rate now" link is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the if clause - wrap instead in ionicPlatform.ready() function.

Be sure to know how to implement plugins in the ionic-framework. Some common pitfalls can be read about here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use this callback:

```
AppRate.preferences.callbacks.onButtonClicked = function(buttonIndex) {

};
```

In this function, check what the buttonIndex of "Rate Now" button is (0, 1, or 2), and then use

`$cordovaAppRate.navigateToAppStore()` to manually navigate to the app store

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, right now i'm using $cordovaAppRate.navigateToAppStore()  instead of the dialog box, but i think it's not working, how do i know if this is not working because the link is invalid?

Comment: I don't understand the last part of what you said. Do you have the correct value in the androidURL and iosURL fields in preferences? If yes it should work

Comment: do you know if i can use a web link in androidURL? for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.finsky&hl=en instead of 'market://details?id=com.google.android.finsky&hl=en'   ? sorry for the silly questions, i'm new with Ionic